# numpy list multiplication against a 2-d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

First off, apologies if this is a clear duplicate. Just getting started with numpy and I totally lack the language to describe my problem properly. Having said that, I'm looking for the correct way to do this in numpy.

I'm trying to multiply a list of ints against a corresponding row in a 2D array in numpy. The 2D array is a 10x10 checkerboard-like array, built like this:

```
import numpy as np

# build 10x10 array of zeros
a = np.array([[0]*10]*10)

# checkerboard out the array
a[::2,::2] = 1
a[1::2,1::2] = 1

# Result (so far so good - look at that checkerboard! Woohoo!)
print(a)
[[1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]]
```

Now, I want to build my range of ints to multiply against my 2D checkerboard:

```
b = np.array(range(5,15))
print(b)
[ 5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14]
```

Looks range-y to me and 10 values long - perfect! Now, in order to solve this, I've enumerated and looped through `b` (my list of ints), and manually multiplied the corresponding row against the int like this:

```
for i, n in enumerate(b):
    a[i] = a[i] * n

print(a)
[[ 5  0  5  0  5  0  5  0  5  0]
 [ 0  6  0  6  0  6  0  6  0  6]
 [ 7  0  7  0  7  0  7  0  7  0]
 [ 0  8  0  8  0  8  0  8  0  8]
 [ 9  0  9  0  9  0  9  0  9  0]
 [ 0 10  0 10  0 10  0 10  0 10]
 [11  0 11  0 11  0 11  0 11  0]
 [ 0 12  0 12  0 12  0 12  0 12]
 [13  0 13  0 13  0 13  0 13  0]
 [ 0 14  0 14  0 14  0 14  0 14]]
```

Nice! While this is what I want to achieve and it *works*, after having seen the power numpy has in working with arrays like this, is this the preferred numpy way?

Comment: The preferred numpy way would be: `a * b[:, None]`. Also note that for creating `b` you could do: `np.arange(5,15)`

Comment: @RaySteam yup! Want to answer it so I can accept your solution? Thanks!

Comment: I'm cool, thanks. Note that if your code works this is better posted on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You're the man! Thanks @RaySteam =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1:

```
(a*b).T
```

`a*b` will initially multiply all columns by the corresponding element in b, and then you just need the transpose.

```
array([[ 5,  0,  5,  0,  5,  0,  5,  0,  5,  0],
       [ 0,  6,  0,  6,  0,  6,  0,  6,  0,  6],
       [ 7,  0,  7,  0,  7,  0,  7,  0,  7,  0],
       [ 0,  8,  0,  8,  0,  8,  0,  8,  0,  8],
       [ 9,  0,  9,  0,  9,  0,  9,  0,  9,  0],
       [ 0, 10,  0, 10,  0, 10,  0, 10,  0, 10],
       [11,  0, 11,  0, 11,  0, 11,  0, 11,  0],
       [ 0, 12,  0, 12,  0, 12,  0, 12,  0, 12],
       [13,  0, 13,  0, 13,  0, 13,  0, 13,  0],
       [ 0, 14,  0, 14,  0, 14,  0, 14,  0, 14]])
```

### Solution 2:

```
b = b.reshape(-1,1) # make it colum vector
a*b
```

returns

```
array([[ 5,  0,  5,  0,  5,  0,  5,  0,  5,  0],
       [ 0,  6,  0,  6,  0,  6,  0,  6,  0,  6],
       [ 7,  0,  7,  0,  7,  0,  7,  0,  7,  0],
       [ 0,  8,  0,  8,  0,  8,  0,  8,  0,  8],
       [ 9,  0,  9,  0,  9,  0,  9,  0,  9,  0],
       [ 0, 10,  0, 10,  0, 10,  0, 10,  0, 10],
       [11,  0, 11,  0, 11,  0, 11,  0, 11,  0],
       [ 0, 12,  0, 12,  0, 12,  0, 12,  0, 12],
       [13,  0, 13,  0, 13,  0, 13,  0, 13,  0],
       [ 0, 14,  0, 14,  0, 14,  0, 14,  0, 14]])
```

Comment: Thanks @makis! I appreciate you explaining some of that for me.